# How can I find out the number of arguments that are actually passed to a bash function?

Tags: bash

Given a bash function:

```
function f1 {
  echo "The function f1 is being called with ??? argument(s)."
  }
```

and two invocations:

```
f1 arg1
f1 arg1 arg2
```

How can I get the number of arguments passed?
Desired output:

```
The function f1 is being called with 1 argument(s).    
The function f1 is being called with 2 argument(s).
```

Comment: Use system variable `$#`. You can see example [here][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568706/checking-number-of-arguments-bash-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
$#
```

see `man bash` for more bash tips

Comment: Thanks. This works as expected:                                                            
     function f1 {
      echo "The function f1 is being called with $# argument(s)."
      }

Answer (score 0):

Using the special argument

```
$#
```

which returns the number of positional arguments given to this invocation of the shell.

From `man bash`...

> $1 - $9       these variables are the positional parameters.
>
> $0            the name of the command currently being executed.
>
> $#            the number of positional arguments given to this
>                 invocation of the shell.
>
> $?            the exit status of the last command executed is
>                 given as a decimal string.  When a command
>                 completes successfully, it returns the exit status
>                 of 0 (zero), otherwise it returns a non-zero exit
>                 status.
>
> $$            the process number of this shell - useful for
>                 including in filenames, to make them unique.
>
> $!            the process id of the last command run in
>                 the background.
>
> $-            the current options supplied to this invocation
>                 of the shell.
>
> $*            a string containing all the arguments to the
>                 shell, starting at $1.
>
> $@            same as above, except when quoted.

These special arguments are very useful for collecting data about the current shell.